# UTFGrid and custom tiles in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, utfgrid

This is my first post here so I apologize in advance if a convention is escaping me in the question format.

I am trying to display information from utfgrid in OpenLayers. I am using custom tiles in a XYZ format which I have setup as a baselayer. I have added a utfgrid layer using the openlayers demo but I cannot get it to work. The goal is to have information show up on mouse over events. The information from UTFGrid is passed to a div on the main html page.

Main html page:

```
<style>
    #attrs {
        height: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
<div id="attrs"></div>
```

main.js

```
var map; 
    function init() { map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {

            restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-157.3251,28.3044,-39.9032,76.5986).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913"),
            units: 'm',
            numZoomLevels: 8,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        } );

        // This is the layer that uses the locally stored tiles
        var OLMCLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
        "Local Tiles", 
        "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", 
        {
        type: 'png',
        isBaseLayer: true});
        map.addLayer(OLMCLayer);
        // This is the end of the layer

        //layer for interactive grid
        var utfgrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.UTFGrid({
        url: "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.json",
        utfgridResolution: 4, // default is 2
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false
        });
        map.addLayer(utfgrid);


        //callback
        var callback = function(infoLookup) {
            var msg = "";
            if (infoLookup) {
                var info;
                for (var idx in infoLookup) {
                // idx can be used to retrieve layer from map.layers[idx]
                    info = infoLookup[idx];
                    if (info && info.data) {

                        msg += " + info.data.csdname + ";   

                    }
                }           
            }
            document.getElementById("attrs").innerHTML = msg;
        };

        var utfControl = new OpenLayers.Control.UTFGrid({
        callback: callback,
        handlerMode: "move"
        });
        map.addControl(utfControl);

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({'geodesic': true}));

        if( ! map.getCenter() ){
            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

        }

    }
```

Comment: it would be easier to identify the error if were to set up an example on jsfiddle or codepen, or some other public facing webpage.